# Shiny app with leaflet - reactive function does not work

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I've started using the Shiny package and I'm having problems with the reactive function. The goal is to create a map which shows the variable posdif per Belgian province, and which can be viewed reactively per sector (nace2d). I get a reactive map as output, but the numbers, colours and labels are not correct. I've played with the position of labels, bins and pals and tried to make them reactive, but nothing seems to work...

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(position = 'right',
                sidebarPanel(
                  selectInput("nace2d","Sector",choices = c("45",'46',"47"),selected = "45"),
                  width = 2),
                mainPanel(leafletOutput("mymap",height = 650,width=605)))
  
  
)

# define server
server <- function(input,output, session){
  
  
  labels <- sprintf(
    "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g jobcreatie",
    projects.df$label, projects.df$posdif
  ) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
  

  bins <- c(0, 500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3500,4000,4500,5000)
  pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = projects.df$posdif, bins = bins)
  
  
  df<-reactive({
    projects.df%>%
      dplyr::filter(nace2d %in% input$nace2d)
  })
  
  

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data=df()) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~pal(posdif), 
        label = labels,
        labelOptions = labelOptions(
          style = list("font-weight"))) %>%
      addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~posdif, opacity = 0.7, title = NULL,
                position = "bottomright")
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```